# How to move to other directory with bash?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

My script

```
#!/bin/bash

for file in *.ats; do
mv $file /home/holmes/procmt
done

cd /home/holmes/procmt
```

All files are moved but I want to change my current directory to /home/holmes/procmt and nothing happens.WHY?
If i run script ./pch.sh,I stay in the same shell.

Comment: The `cd` happens, but the script runs *within it's own shell* and so the `cd` occurs within the context of that new shell. Once it completes, it's back at your original shell (your prompt) and doesn't affect that environment. You can execute your script within the context of your current shell using `.` (dot). Try, `$ . myscript` (`$` is your prompt).

Answer (score 0):

The shell running the script moved, but the shell you were typing in when you started the script stayed put.  If you precede the name of your shell script with `.` (dot space) it will run in 'your' shell.

Comment: No it is the same.Take a look at my edit.

Comment: By "moved" I meant the its current directory changed.